# Double Buffering a JFrame

Tags: swing, jframe, jpanel, double, buffer

[Warning, I am a beginner, I have little knowledge about JFrame and I am just getting started, but your help would be greatly appreciated!]

So, here is my Problem: I am currently working on something extremely simple, just a red rectangle moving across the screen and I know how beginner-like that must sound.

My current Code:

```
package movement;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Movement extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Movement m = new Movement();

    m.setSize(1000, 1000);
    m.setTitle("Movement");
    m.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    m.setVisible(true);
    m.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


}

public void paint (Graphics g){
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    int x = 100;
    int y = 900;

    while(x < 1000 && y > 0){
    //System.out.println("Success");    
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(x+width, y-height, 200, 200);
    //g.fillRect(x+width, y-height, 200, 200);
    try{
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch(InterruptedException e){
    }
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(x+width, y-height, 200, 200);
    //g.fillRect(x+width, y-height, 200, 200);
    width=width+1;
    height=height+1;

    }


}

}
```

So as you can see it works, but the image stutters and flicks a bit, since there is only a single Buffer. I heard that adding a JPanel would allow me to double buffer and have a way smoother experience, but since I am a real beginner I wouldn't know how to implement it here. I am not sure how a JPanel would help here and in which way to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Swing is double buffered by default. You are overriding the paint() method of the frame and have not invoked super.paint(...) so you are losing the default double buffering.

> I heard that adding a JPanel would allow me to double buffer and have a way smoother experience

Yes, this is the proper way to do custom painting. It is not difficult all you do is override the `paintComponent()` method of the JPanel and add the panel to the frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and examples.

Also, you should NEVER have a while loop with a Thread.sleep() in a painting method. To do animation you should use a `Swing Timer`. The tutorial link I provided above also has a section on `Timers` or you can search the forum/web for examples.